# Is it possible to create a mutually exclusive group inside another one with argparse (Python)?

Tags: python, argparse

I am using *argparse* in Python, and I need to do this in console:

```
python3 my_program.py (-a | -b) | (-c | -d)
```

I read several forums and I guess the answer is no, but just in case. Is it possible?

Comment: Possibly related bug http://bugs.python.org/issue11588

Comment: Ok, so for the moment, it seems that it is not possible to make nested groups.

Comment: How would that differ from a single mutually exclusive group consisting of `-a`, `-b`, `-c`, and `-d`?

Comment: The linked issue refers to groups of arguments that *must* be used together, i.e., use `-a` and `-b` together (not one without the other), *or* `-c` and `-d` together, but not all four.

Comment: The guy who is making the suggestion (in the forum of the link) says that "This also means that argparse will need to support nested groups." So for that reason I supposed that now is not possible.

Comment: The request in issue11588 was for a more complicated logical structure, mixing inclusive and exclusive groups.  The rudimentary nesting that I demonstrate in my answer is inadequate for that.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to take anyone's word for it - try it.

```
import argparse
parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
g = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
g1 = g.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
g1.add_argument('-a')
g1.add_argument('-b')
g2 = g.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
g2.add_argument('-c')
g2.add_argument('-d')
print [a.dest for a in g._group_actions]
print [a.dest for a in g1._group_actions]
print [a.dest for a in g2._group_actions]
parser.print_help()
```

producing:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']  # actions in group g
['a', 'b']
['c', 'd']
usage: stack23292325.py [-h] [[-a A | -b B] [-c C | -d D]
```

`g1` and `g2` can be defined in another group `g`, but the net effect it to make the 4 actions mutually exclusive.  Which, if you think about it, is logically correct.

The usage line is not quite correct.  The first '[' comes from `g`, but there's no '|' or ']' for that group.  The usage formatter has not concept of nesting groups.  It just tries to format the 3 groups at though they were independent.

But you could write your own usage line.

This kind of nesting makes more sense is `g` is an `argument_group`.  Then the actions will be placed in a distinct help group.  The two kinds of groups are functionally quite different.

http://bugs.python.org/issue17218 uses this ability to nest a mutually_exclusive_group in an argument_group to add a 'title' and 'description' to the MXG.  There's an example of this the argparse unittest file `Lib/test/test_argparse.py`.

Comment: Hello and thak you very much. You are right, the four actions are mutually exlusive. But I want to have the possibility to use -a with -c or -a with -d, and on the other side, -b with -c or -b with -d. But never -a with -b or -c with -d. What you are doing with that code is almost the same to add only one mutually exclusive group with -a, -b, -c and -d as their arguments, aren't you?

Comment: The current 'nesting', is effectively, the same as putting them all in one group.  What you just described looks like 2 MXgroups without nesting.  But feel free to contribute to issue11588 if you have ideas on how to express (and implement) complicated mix&match constraints.