# Mutually exclusive groups with required arguments if a specific group is chosen

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

I'm parsing a set of options for the Minesweeper game. There are two groups of option:

1. Predefined grid size (difficulty): `--level easy|medium|hard`
2. Custom grid size: `--rows 16 --columns 24 --mines 40`

I want to achive with ArgumentParser that user can choose a level OR a custom size which, however, requires all three arguments (-r/-c/-m). If both level and any of custom size options are specified, an exception should be raised; same if level is not specified but not all three arguments are specified.

This sound logical to me but doesn't work:

```py
parser = ArgumentParser(description="Minesweeper game")
grid_size = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
grid_size.add_argument("-l", "--level", type=str)
custom_grid = grid_size.add_argument_group()
custom_grid.add_argument("-r", "--rows", type=int, required=True)
custom_grid.add_argument("-c", "--columns", type=int, required=True)
custom_grid.add_argument("-m", "--mines", type=int, required=True)
```

Problem is that `python minesweeper.py -l easy -r 40 -c 40 -m 40` should raise an error, instead it pass the ArgumentParser checks.

I'va also tried to include `-l` into an argument group itself, no luck. I'm currently doing "post parsing" checks but at this point I want to know if this is possible using ArgumentParser.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to create a mutually exclusive group inside another one with argparse (Python)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23292325/is-it-possible-to-create-a-mutually-exclusive-group-inside-another-one-with-argp)

Comment: groups can't be nested.  You have to do your own testing after parsing.

Comment: @Woodford a bit: in the ticket linked in that question there is a proposal for a group of "all or nothing" arguments. But it's not possible because, as hpaulj said, groups can't be nested. Thank you both!

Answer (score 0):

You may try [ArgumentParser Subcommands](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#sub-commands), you could create a parser for a given command; in your case one customizable grid and other fixed from difficulty level.

```py
from argparse import ArgumentParser

parser = ArgumentParser(description="Minesweeper Game")

parser.add_argument("-s", "--something", help="Something help")
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help="Subcommand help")

level_grid = subparsers.add_parser('level_grid')
custom_grid = subparsers.add_parser('custom_grid')

level_grid.add_argument("-l", "--level", dest="level", default="hard", type=str)

custom_grid.add_argument("-r", "--rows", type=int, default=0)
custom_grid.add_argument("-c", "--columns", type=int, default=0)
custom_grid.add_argument("-m", "--mines", type=int, default=0)

args = parser.parse_args()

print ("args => ", args)
```

You will have:

```bash
$ python3 minesweeper.py level_grid --level "hard"  
args =>  Namespace(level='hard', something=None)

$ python3 minesweeper.py custom_grid -r 16 --columns 24 -m 16  
args =>  Namespace(columns=24, mines=16, rows=16, something=None)
```